# Notifications are grouped when sending only "data" params

Tags: push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to send push-notifications to Android.

If I send notification with`notification payload`then they are not getting grouped.
How can I separate them if I use only `data` in the notification?
Example:

```
{ 
   "to":"eNu-qhBtQdI:APA91bFewNZjgMNep6wqsrECDLXMcaPsBMIFktGl77d4l5cWIiqebN6aDs-tO2wHm0K82Qoayzlt3LQ0VtXm12CAhk8wNMyJX8fc0I1XAIdqp3zOa0o6hwYpnYwdOAeGXEhYVCw3sERJ",
   "data":{
       "body":"great match",
       "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
       "sound":"default",
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by grouped? Do you mean that the request to send the messages are being grouped, or do you mean that the notifications shown on the device is being grouped?

Answer (score 0):

If you manually build a notification in your `onMessageReceived` handler in the app and use the same ID for each notification, they will replace eachother.

Docs for [NotificationManager.notify()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(java.lang.String,int,android.app.Notification))):

> Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with the same tag and id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

So if you want them to be **not** replaced, you need to use different IDs while building the notification.

Answer (score 0):

> - **Notifications delivered when your app is in the background.** - In this
>     case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A
>     user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
> - **Messages with both notification and data payload.** In this case, the
>     notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data
>     payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher
>     Activity.

[Firebase downstream messages.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#sample-receive)

> they are not getting grouped.

they are not getting grouped because Push message sent from Firebase Console is a notification no matter what, you cannot send data payload from Console, its a limitation of Console.
So if you are sending a notification from Console, then it is getting delivered to device's system tray where OS is generating notification for you and every notification id is different.

However in the case of data payload, you are creating the notification id yourself using some code like this:

```java
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// NOTE: mId should be different for every push if you don't want them to group, something like a mId = new Random().nextInt(9999) may work
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

In case you don't know, a Push message from firebase is divided into two parts - notification and data payload. [Read More.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)